# Js not found spring mvc

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Hello everyone I caught an issue with js files in jsp I have a warning

```
 <script src="<c:url value="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"/>"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>"></script>

<script src="<c:url value="bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js"/>"></script>

<script src="<c:url value="dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"/>"></script>
```

My jsp can't access to js files

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
    in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/bap/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'

can someone tell me what's the problem please, thank you

Comment: How your structure looks like. If you map the url /resourcs/** to /resources, then it should be under resources. e.g: <script src="<c:url value="resources/dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"/>"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First of all let us understand `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />`.

Here you are configuring the `DispatcherServlet` of spring MVC to map all `HTTP` request that has a pattern `/resources/**` to the physical directory `/resources/`. This is done to Put resources like `cs`, `js` or `images` into this folder `webapp/resources` and serve as the static content to the web-app.
Reference: [Spring MVC - include JS or CSS files in a JSP page](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/)

Now, you can resolve your issue in several ways, one of them is explained below:

- Create a directory named `resources` inside `WebContent`. Move all the static contents inside its respective directory, e.g. Move `jquery.min.js` to `WebContent/resources/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js` and similarly for others.
- Append `/resources/` to the url. In the JSP pages, access the static content as

`<script src="<c:url value="/resources/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"/>"></script>`

I hope this helps you, feel free to comment for further assistance!

Comment: I found the solution I just add  <script src="<c:url value="/resources/dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"/>"></script> thank's to yu all